# Chrome Cast Sender "session_error" NOT_FOUND

Tags: chromecast

I can't get a basic sender app set up. I've tried the [CastHelloText](https://github.com/googlecast/CastHelloText-chrome/blob/master/chromehellotext.html) sender example, put in my own AppId and get an error immediately after `chrome.cast.requestSession()` is called when I select my device from the top-right Google Cast extension button. My receiver is based off of [Cast-Simple-Receiver](https://github.com/googlecast/Cast-Simple-Receiver). I've done the whole unplugging power/plugging back in thing to restart ChromeCast, but that doesn't resolve my issue.

Resources out there seem kind of slim at the moment, but is there a place that explains everything in-depth without having to jump from site to site? Also, take a look at the image I've attached. I can't figure out what that other URL is supposed to be.

My specific error from the `requestSession()` looks like this:

`{code: "session_error", description: "NOT_FOUND", details: null}`

EDIT: I've verified that I can connect to the default `chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID` but my receiver app can't be connected to. I've registered my device and restarted it multiple times. I've now removed it and am trying to re-register it to see if that helps (even though it said it was ready for dev).

[image: Chrome Cast Developer Console]

Comment: I believe the website URL is just a website address that provides your end users with information about the app after it has been published.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check these; hopefully they get things sorted out:

- Make sure you have registered your chromecast device on the developer console. Double check the serial number since sometimes it is hard to read it.
- During the chromecast setup, there was a box stating something like "Send the serial number ..", make sure that is checked
- Wait 1/2 hour or so and reboot your chromecast
- Check whether you can access `http://<chromecast-ip>:9222` from a chrome browser on the same wifi network; if you can, then your device is ready for development

As for the area on the image that you have pointed to, that is more for informational purposes at this point

Comment: Oy! I had a digit wrong in the serial number incorrect! Hopefully that'll help. So did I register someone else's serial number then?

Comment: Note, the serial number is NOT the MAC address... despite both being 12 digits long and alphanumeric.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be sufficient to only boot the Chromecast device by unplugging it –  or it was just a coincidence that the Web contents seemed instantly available on 192.168.1.20:9222 (in my case) after the reboot.

Comment: @Gatada, I wasn't sure how to reboot, actually, without unplugging. Is there a "Reboot" option somewhere?

Comment: Easiest is to just unplug and plug it back in.

Comment: There is a reboot option in the chromecast application (on Mac OS X in my case....probably on other OS too). Downloadable from here: https://cast.google.com/chromecast/setup

Comment: after 4h of pulling my precious and already receding hair, chromecast reboot did the trick :facepalm:

Comment: Hey, I am struggling with this error, though I am only using `chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID`. Though I have description null as well. Do I need to register my DEVICE when using the default receiver while developing?

Comment: @A.Blanc have solved this problem?