# How to be sure that my application is properly configured?

Tags: ios, google-cast

I don't understand how to access my application on the Chromecast I always get this error `GCKErrorCodeApplicationNotFound`. Maybe I misconfigured my application on *Google Cast SDK Developer Console* but I did't see how.

Everything seems to be OK except that my application code don't seems to be working.
How can I find my Developer ID to contact the support ?

List of delegates call:

```
-[CCViewController deviceDidComeOnline:]
-[CCViewController deviceManagerDidConnect:]
-[CCViewController deviceManager:volumeDidChangeToLevel:isMuted:]
volumeLevel: 1
isMuted: 0
-[CCViewController deviceManager:didFailToConnectToApplicationWithError:]

- (void)deviceManager:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager didFailToConnectToApplicationWithError:(NSError *)error { NSLog(@"error: %@", [GCKError enumDescriptionForCode:error.code]); }
```

---

After various test I can access the chromecast with the application ID of the default streaming app but not with mine so it's an application issue. Does anyone successfully configure his receiver application ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Developer ID anymore; you manage your apps and devices yourself. Please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813) answer and see if that helps you. If not, come back to get more help.

Comment: My serial number was wrong I misinterpret an `O` for a `0`. Thanks my app works now.