# IOS Launch Application to chromecast not working

Tags: ios, google-cast, chromecast

I created my IOS application based on CastHelloText example, I can connect perfectly to chromecast but when launching the app, nothing happens

Sometimes I see a message on my TV saying "brain freeze"

in the app, the delegate method:

```
- (void)deviceManager:(GCKDeviceManager *)deviceManager
didConnectToCastApplication:(GCKApplicationMetadata *)applicationMetadata
                  sessionID:(NSString *)sessionID
        launchedApplication:(BOOL)launchedApplication
```

is never called!

I think I can be setting something wrong in the developer console, When I check the option `IOS`, there is a field that says `App URL` and not sure I should enter there!

Is there any option to call directly to a URL without using an app id?

Answer (score 2):

I use the default Media Player AppID for my test `kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID` until I figured out how to make my application work.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21618176/chrome-cast-sender-session-error-not-found/21619494#21619494) would help.

Comment: As a side note, please do not use these "hardcoded" app ids since that can change at any time without any notice; instead you can use app ids that are available through each SDK:
For Android apps: CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID,
For Chrome apps: chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID,
For iOS apps: kGCKMediaDefaultReceiverApplicationID

Comment: Thanks, but maybe it should be great to have it set by default on the iOS demo app like on [CastVideos-chrome](https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-chrome) sample app ?

Comment: Open a feature request for that project on Github please.