# Removed Chromecast App now MediaRouteButton won't show

Tags: android, chromecast

I added an application to the Chromecast Console. I imported the sample Cast Hello Android example from Github. This worked right away when I added the app_id I got from the Chromecast Console. I realized the URL was pointed to the wrong place. Changing the URL did not seem to have any effect so I removed the Application.

I have re-added multiple applications; now pointed at this same URL and other URLs. Running the  same android application that was showing the MediaRouteButton and casting correctly is now no longer showing the MediaRouteButton. I thought this may be related to the removed application. However, I've changed the app_id to the new ones multiple times to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After creating an app, it may take a little while for that to become available for your chromecast device; re-plugging the chromecast device can help. If that didn't solve your issue, please take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813) answer and follow the steps there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was able to find the fix.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

The problem was related to the "namespace" item in the strings.xml. After changing the package name of the project I had to update this item as well. Doing so to reflect the actual package name fixed the problem right away.