# Route selector icon not showing all of a sudden

Tags: android, google-cast

I've got the app_Id and submitted the chromecast devise for testing(it shows ready for testing). I've tested my app for a few times. Moved all the chromecast logic to a singleton class. The code is exactly the same as mentioned in the android sender tutorial. Tested it there too a few times after moving to singleton. Then all of a sudden, the rout selector icon stopped showing up in the app. callbacks are not triggered.

In the very beginning, I was able to select the route icon but, google api client creation showed error `2400 failed to create for unknown reason`

The only thing I tried before and after it worked was, I tried to use the android companion library for chromecast.

Did google unwhitelist my devise for some reason?

I've restarted phone, my pc, chromecast, router. I'm thinking to reset the chromecast now.

**Update:** I've tried running the VideoBrowser app(sample app given by android) in debug, this used to work before(show router selector), it is not working now. It should be definitely the chromecast receiver then. Any way to force it to accept testing?

Thanks.

Comment: You said it worked at some poin and then stopped working. When it was working, were you using your own app id? How about when it stopped? Can you access http://<chromecast-ip>:9222 from a chrome browser on your network?

Comment: I've created an AppId on developer console. Even when it stopped working, it is the same AppId, I've created another appid in the developer console, this did not work as well. The url of the chromecast is 192.168.1.137 in lan and it did not work for the port you mentioned.

Comment: Just checked. It worked with the first app_id i've been using. Dont know why.

Comment: More update on this, it could be because of the 'publish' option that you select on the application in the developer console. I've set it to true.

Comment: I suggest you follow the steps in this post to make sure your device is whitelisted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813 If your device is not whitelisted, you won;t be able to debug your receiver; publishing your app will mask that issue