# ChromeCast(google cast) can't find app name

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, whitelist

ChromeCast  (google cast) can't find my app name.

I already registered the app in the whitelist.

I can find and launch apps/YouTube, apps/ChromeCast, apps/OldAppName,

but not apps/NewAppName.

Why so? How can I do any thing?

thanks a lot.

Sincoew

---

Hi Ali Naddaf,
Thanks you for your reply.
I already checked each step by your link again, My app ID is already in whitelist.

I used "//www.gstatic.com/cast/sdk/libs/receiver/2.0.0/cast_receiver.js"
in my receiver app.

but when I Invoke receiver use new app ID, It's return below Error on receiver source code.
(google default)`enter code here`

```
    case Message.CODE.ERROR_NET_ABORTED:
return new Message(
      Message.getLocaleString('BrainFreeze'),
      Message.getLocaleString('Sorry'),
      Message.getLocaleString('ActivityAborted'));
```

On ChromeCast "receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js",
I can found my app use app ID, such as "192.168.xxx.xxx:8008/apps/AppID",
This rule is still can work???

Thanks a lot.
Sincoew

---

The error source code is in home screen,
http://192.168.xxx.xxx:9222/devtools/devtools.html?xxxxxx
"message.js" file,
This is ChromeCast default home screen source code

I use below receiver:

```
//github.com/googlecast/cast-custom-receiver/blob/master/sample_media_receiver.html
```

sender:

```
1 //github.com/googlecast/cast-sender-tool-chrome
2 our iOS app sender, (google sample)
```

ps. default app is normal work, YouTube/ChromeCast/old app-ID(version 1.0 js)
and I can found below page use browser,

```
"192.168.xxx.xxx:8008/apps/YouTube"
"192.168.xxx.xxx:8008/apps/Chromecast"
"192.168.xxx.xxx:8008/apps/old app-ID"
```

but can't found

```
"192.168.xxx.xxx:8008/apps/new app-ID"
```

Thanks a lot,
Sincoew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely your device is not whitelisted. You need to register your chromecast device for your appid and then, follow the instructions in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813) to troubleshoot. Also read the [development site](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) for chromecast; it has valuable info.

Comment: Hi, thanks you for your reply.
but I already register my appid, 
and my whitelist show "ready on test".

If normal work, I can found "Device-IP:8008/apps/App-ID" on browser, right? (app-description.xml)

Comment: Read the instructions in the post I gave you, there is a step to check if your device is whitelisted or not

Comment: Hi Ali Naddaf, 
Thanks you for your reply. 
I already checked each step by your link again, 
and add more info on my test, can you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I can access <chromecast-ip>:9222, and see home screen log

Comment: You mentioned you get an error on a piece of code that has BrainFreeze, etc. Where is that code? Which receiver are you using? What sender are you using? You need to share the code that you are using. Also try using the default app id and see if that works

Comment: Hi, I add more info at post,
Thanks you for your help

Comment: FYI, for those who may face this... you also need to enable "Send this Chromecast's serial number to Google when checking for updates." You can do this by: Chromecast App -> Device (name) -> General -> check box.

Comment: That is included in the answer that I gave (follow the post that I link there)