# Chromecast, Styled Media Receiver, gray bars

Tags: chromecast

Can we change the background color used for the bars which display on top and below a video, when a video doesn't fit the screen?
By default it is a dark gray, which is very distracting.

I tried this to see if it can be changed at all. But it didn't change:

```
.background {

  background: center no-repeat url(my_background_url)
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

 ...
}
```

Comment: Try .background instead of background.

Comment: Just a typo, edited it. The background image is showing, that works. I can see the white background (255,255,255) too for a second, before the image is loaded. But when a video plays the color of the bars (above and below or left and right) is gray.

Comment: Unfortunately, at the moment, I can't test on a real device (I moved buildings), so take my suggestion w/ a grain of salt.  What I would do in your case is to use Chrome remote debugging <ip of Chromecast>:9222, then debug your styled receiver, using the inspector, see if you can't find what element the gray bars are coming from, then set that element to what you want. Once you have something that works, fix your style sheet.

Comment: If you noticed that changing your stylesheet cannot address that, then open a feature request on our issue tracker for us to look into it.

Comment: @AliNaddaf add the link and I will. Les Vogel: should I be able to access the Chromecast directly in the browser through (http://)ip:9222 ? Because I can't. The device is registered with it's serial.

Comment: Enabled 'Send this Chromecast's serial..." and I can now see it. Thanks for that.

Comment: If the device is whitelisted, then you should have access to port 9222, so please double check on that by following these steps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/2765813  Only after making your device work with that port and when you are certain that the CSS changes on your side is not enough, file a feature request at: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/list

Comment: I am still not sure if I am doing something wrong. I only use the sample CSS with my custom images. If I try to add background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); to .body or .gcpa or some of the others. The file is not processed at all.

Comment: Again, try doing things in the inspector, and see if you can't figure out what what need.  Then put it in the file.  Try using the !Important css attribute on your items.

Comment: @LesVogel-GoogleDevRel I couldn't figure this out, so I solved it with a custom receiver. If you have time to try it and post an answer, please do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding this to your custom stylesheet will do the trick:

```
#player video {
    background-color: black;
}
```

However, I think Google should not set a background-color on the video element (currently #111 I think)