# Can Linux be used for Chrome cast (chrome) development?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, chromecast, google-cast

I am new to Chrome cast. I ask this question because I can't get a helloText sample app running.
I am hosting the receiver on a static local IP address. Both the sender and receiver were cloned from the sample apps repository for Google cast. However the same app ran successfully on a Mac. On Linux it return a 'session_error'.
My app is registered with Google Cast SDK and all the options have be marked as instructed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer provided above is correct. The specific case of which I was experiencing is the `https server` that was being used on linux had to be added as an exception (as I was using a local server). This could not be managed on the chrome cast and hence the receiver could not to located/launched. I had previously used a `http server` on Mac and it worked just as well once this change was made. Since the receiver could not be located a `SESSION_ERROR` was occurring.

Answer (score 0):

[SESSION_ERROR](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast) means a session could not be created, or a session was invalid. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21619494/6143482) from Ali Nadaff might help:

> Make sure you have registered your chromecast device on the developer
>   console. Double check the serial number since sometimes it is hard to
>   read it. During the chromecast setup, there was a box stating
>   something like "Send the serial number ..", make sure that is checked
>   Wait 1/2 hour or so and reboot your chromecast Check whether you can
>   access http://:9222 from a chrome browser on the same
>   wifi network; if you can, then your device is ready for development